# How to display sample size when use `geom_histogram()`?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
iris %>% 
  ggplot(.,mapping=aes(x=Sepal.Length))+
  geom_histogram(binwidth= 0.1)+
  stat_n_text()+
  facet_wrap(~Species)

Error: stat_n_text requires the following missing aesthetics: y
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Above plot script get error.  After remove `stat_n_text()+`,ggplot works well.

Is `stat_n_text()` not workable with `geom_histogram()`?If yes,any alternative function?

Comment: It might be useful to know from what package the `stat_n_text()` function is. And what the expected output would be.

Comment: Probably because it is only meant to work "For a strip plot or scatterplot produced using the package ggplot2.." See http://search.r-project.org/library/EnvStats/html/stat_n_text.html

Comment: @stefan,then what's the alternative to `stat_n_text` of `geom_histogram`?

Comment: One approach would be to use geom_text e.g. `geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(..count.. > 0, paste0("n = ", ..count..), "")), y = 0, stat = "bin", binwidth = 0.1, nudge_y = -.2)`